# Spritekit game: How change object display in contact

Tags: xcode5, sprite-kit, game-physics

Currently in my game using Spritekit, when the character collide with the object, it just end the game. But I want to change it a little bit more real, if character hits the object, the object either can be cracked, broken or bended so that the character can go through it.

Now, I have Character defined as:

```
        //Create physics body
    _Character.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody   bodyWithCircleOfRadius:_Character.size.height /2];
    _Character.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    _Character.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
    _Character.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CharacterCategory;
    _Character.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = worldCategory | ObjectCategory;
    _Character.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = worldCategory | ObjectCategory;
```

where worldCategory and ObjectCategory defined as:

```
    static const uint32_t worldCategory = 1 << 1;
    static const uint32_t ObjectCategory = 1 << 2;
```

My object is defined as no dynamic object, so normally it won't change

```
  SKSpriteNode* Object1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:_ObjectTexture1];
    [Object1 setScale:2];
    Object1.position = CGPointMake(0, y);
    Object1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:Object1.size];
    Object1.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

    ...
        _ObjectTexture1 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Object1"];
        _ObjectTexture1.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;

    ...  
        Object1.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = ObjectCategory;
        Object1.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = CharacterCategory;
```

But I want it not change in some conditions, and change (cracked, or broken, or bended) in some conditions. How do we implement the behaviour of the object under contact? I am thinking is in each condition can replace the Image for the object, (So I can simulate cracked or broken -maybe, but bend is quite difficult). How is your solution here? I am very new to game stuffs so really stuck here.

Ps: edited my post to make the question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can either subclass your character node and add a hitCount property on it, or simply save the count in the userData property of the character node. Then in the contact delegate, you simply check the hitCount, increment it, set the image accordingly or end the game as the condition requires.

I am guessing the characterCategory has value 3.

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    SKNode *firstBody;
    SKNode *secondBody;

    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)
    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA.node;
        secondBody = contact.bodyB.node;
    }
    else
    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB.node;
        secondBody = contact.bodyA.node;
    }

    if (firstBody.physicsBody.categoryBitMask == objectCategory && secondBody.physicsBody.categoryBitMask == characterCategory)
    {
        (CharacterSprite*) secondBody.hitCount++;
        int hitCount = (CharacterSprite*) secondBody.hitCount;

    switch(hitCount)
    {

        case 1: 
            secondBody.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"cracked"];
            break;

        case 2:
            [secondBody removeFromParent];
            //whatever action you need to implement here.
            break;

        default:
            break;

    }

    }
}
```

This is an example of the CharacterSprite class (or whatever class you want to add the hitCount property in. This is a new file.

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
@interface CharacterSprite : SKSpriteNode

@property NSInteger hitCount;

@end
```

Comment: Its also my idea and I already stated on my post how I will trigger the event. But my question here is how to code the image changing upon the contact (collision, when check count is satisfied).

Comment: What is your hitCount here ? In the switch, what is case 2, why we remove secondBody, actually I don't get the meaning of bodyA,B also. Looks like I can change a cracked image for the object. How about the broken object?

Comment: What is CharacterSprite*, for my Xcode it is undefined object

Comment: Have you not implemented a contact delegate in your application yet?

Comment: I already implemented it: @interface MyScene () <SKPhysicsContactDelegate> { SKNode* CharacterSprite; } is that what you mean ?

Comment: CharacterSprite is a subclassed SKSpriteNode, with an additional property called HitCount. The hitcount variable is incremented each time the sprite is detected in the contact delegate, and the required action is carried out. In this case, I was assuming that on the first hit, the object needs to be shown as cracked, and  on the second, it is to be removed.

Comment: My character will not hit one object again and again. Let's say I have defined a "count" as integer and it increase during the game. Then I will check the value of this integer and base on that value to define how the object change in contact. Say if ( 3 < count < 5 ) then in contact object will show crack. If (5 <= count < 7) object will be broken and fall apart. If count > 7 then object will be bended when character go over it.

Comment: You can definitely expand on what I have written in the answer.

Comment: But (CharacterSprite*) looks like a wrong gramma Bro! If you have a running version then I could test on that and know the meaning of each part. Thank you!

Comment: All the code used in this answer is indicative, and only for the purpose of understanding. You will have to implement something based on this.